# Drunkenly said something offensive to a coworker

Tags: colleagues, relationships

So. Christmas dinner office party. Drank way too much too fast. Told a coworker he reminded me of a cow, but I didn't mean anything bad by it. He has this sort of "cow looking at the cars from behind the barb wire" energy that I think it's pretty cool. A very relaxed/relaxing demeanor. It obviously didn't come out that way (not even sure there's a good way to communicate that tbh). The rest of my coworkers laughed it off but now, sober, I'm mortified thinking about it.

I (thankfully) don't spend that many hours at work with this person, two hours a day at most (he works mornings, I work afternoons). Should I apologize? Try to explain what I meant? Or just pretend it didn't happen at all?

EDIT: edited out the mildly in the title since yeah, it was straight offensive. I did try to explain myself at the moment but I don't remember it going great.

Comment: You might consider sending him a link to this question with a brief explanation that you posted it.

Comment: Can someone please explain `sort of "cow looking at the cars from behind the barb wire" energy` ??

Comment: Welcome new user.  Actually this is a great question, and timely after new years  :)

Comment: I think it's silly that this is voted closed.  Why?

Comment: Mawg: I think it means “I drank much too much in a very short time and the effect hasn’t quite gone yet”.

Answer (score 16):

Just quickly, quietly, and privately speak to the coworker.

> hey Bob, I  know i got a bit brash at the party.  If i was rude to you, i just want to apologize.

Leave it at that

The less of a deal you make of it, the better.

Comment: Yes.  There's really no need to over-egg an apology here - it looks as though it was laughed off in this instance, so no one seemed to take huge offense at this.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the conditional apology. "If I was rude to you" isn't as bad as the "I'm sorry if anyone took offence" non-apology, but still implies you don't know if you were being rude. "I'm sorry I was rude to you" would be better and more direct.

Comment: @LaconicDroid that's not the conditional apology.  The conditional apology is "If You were offended by what I said, I apologize".  The way I phrased it is appropriate because the OP seems unsure.

Comment: @RichardU If/Then couldn't be more conditional . Nothing says "I'm sorry" better than plain old "I'm sorry". No ifs, ands or buts.

Answer (score 7):

> Hey Bob, I want to apologize.
>   I love your very relaxed, cool demeanor and wanted to give you a compliment.
>   Somehow my totally drunk mind went to cows looking at the distant.
>   I have no idea where that came from. 
> I hope I didn't offend you badly.

Comment: I'd change the last line to a simple "I'm sorry."

Answer (score 5):

It's not "mildly offensive" if you just compared him to a cow unless you corrected yourself immediately and explained what you meant.

I assume here you didn't. Your remark was simply offensive then. Comparing people to animals such as cows, monkeys and similar is considered very offensive.

You should ask him to grab a coffee together or similar and explain what you wrote here.

Comment: The author could also just apologize, the relationship has already been damaged, I personally wouldn't want anything to do with somebody who called me a "cow".

Comment: I don't know that you can explain away being called a cow. If OP explained it the way he did in his post I would still be insulted.

Comment: I was called a cow in the past. And then the person explained I had most beautiful eyes, just like a cow. It helped a bit :)